# How to compile and install JBE

Tags: software-installation

Help I just downloaded JBE (Java bytecode editor) when I extracted it (because it was in a zip file when I downloaded it) it comes up with a folder named "bin", a folder named "src",versoion.txt, jbe.sh, jbe.bat and a copying.txt file. Please how to compile ,install, and run the application ?. I am using Xubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

JBE can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install libbytecode-java libasm3-java
```

Comment: Ok i done when you suggested but how do i run it  sorry for the question i am a beginner in linux